# How to read cstrings from char**?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, char-traits

I have a `char**` (a null terminate array: last element of array is NULL) returned by a function (which I can not change):

```
char** ptar = get_ptar();
```

I want to iterate over it and pass its value to another function (again which I can not change):

```
collection(int index, char* str);
```

I have this code so far:

```
int I = 0;
while (*ptar != 0) 
{
  collection(i, (char*)(ptar));
  ptar++; i++;
}
```

But it passes garbage value.

Is there a better approach get string out of a null-terminated array?

---

Related question:

Is there a way to get the length of `char** ptar` using C++11's:

`std::char_traits<?>::length`

Comment: `collection(i, *ptar);`

Comment: Don't use C-style casts, use C++ casts. If you use a cast other than static_cast, something is probably (but not always) wrong. In this case, you would see that `static_cast<char*>(ptar)` does not compile, and this is your hint that something is wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, you nailed it! Thanks.

Comment: @Neil Kirk, Thanks for the tips. I am avoiding casting, it is just a middle tier where I need to pipe `char*`s to another function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for ( int i = 0; *( ptar + i ) != 0; i++ ) 
{
  collection( i, *( ptar + i ) );
}
```

Or

```
for ( int i = 0; ptar[i] != 0; i++ ) 
{
  collection( i, ptar[i] );
}
```

In C++ 2011 instead of integral constant 0 as null pointer expression you may use `nullptr`

To find the length of `ptar`  you can do this:

```
int n = 0;

while ( ptar[n] ) ++n;
```